# Are class methods also singleton if a class is singleton?

Tags: typescript, singleton

I have a class which I recently made singleton:

```
class ABC {
  private static instance: ABC

  private constructor() {}

  //This is only for unit-testing
  static reset() {
     this.instance = null
  }

  public static getInstance(): ABC {
     if (!this.instance) {
        this.instance = new ABC()
     }
     return ABC.instance
  }

    public async getData(params): Promise<string> {
        switch (someCondition()) {
            case A:
            case B:
            case C:
                return await this.method1(someParam)
            case D:
                return this.method2()
            case E:
                try {
                    return this.anotherMethod()
                } catch (err) {
                    throw err
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote unit tests for this -

```
    describe("ABC should be singleton", () => {
        it("should return the same instance of ABC", async () => {
            expect(ABC.getInstance()).toBe(ABC.getInstance())
        })
        it("should not return the same instance of ABC in case the it is null", async () => {
            const instance1 = await ABC.getInstance()
            //resetting the value
            ABC.reset()
            const instance2 = await ABC.getInstance()
            expect(instance1).not.toBe(instance2)
        })
        it("should return the same instance of ABC in case getCredential is called with the same parameters", async () => {
            const instance1 = await ABC.getInstance().getData({},  {
                param1, param2
            })
            const instance2 = await ABC.getInstance().getData({},  {
                param1, param2
            })
            expect(instance1).toBe(instance2)
        })
    })
```

The first two test cases pass, but the third doesn't. I don't understand why? Is it right to assume that ones a class is made singleton, the methods called on it are also singleton?

Also, if ABC is first called with A,B params and then called with D,C params, will it initialize again?

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] others can use to see your issue clearly with their own IDEs and without any dependencies on third party libraries or private or undeclared things or pseudocode.  The only problem present should be the one you're asking about, so no compiler errors unless you're asking about compiler errors.

Comment: Are you sure your third test is correct? You call getData and check a referential equality. As I see, `getData` returns promise of string, so naming the result of it instance is also not correct. It should be ` expect(instance1).toEqual(instance2)` ad if so please rename instance1 and instance2 to resultData1 and resultDAta2.